Ошибка ssl сертифката в aiohttp/vkbottle
Пытаюсь запустить на работе следующий код из документации VkBottle:
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message

bot = Bot(token=token)

@bot.on.message(text="Привет")
async def hi_handler(message: Message):
    users_info = await bot.api.users.get(message.from_id)
    await message.answer("Привет, {}".format(users_info[0].first_name))

bot.run_forever()

Выдаёт следующую ошибку:
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host api.vk.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)')]
Дело в том, что дома у меня не возникает такой ошибки. Однако на работе, где у меня развёрнута локальная сеть возникают подобные ошибки. Я проверял передачу сертификата через Openssl, введя следующую команду: openssl s_client -connect api.vk.com:443 -4 <<< "Q"
Я даже пытался развернуть его на абсолютно чистой windows находящейся на виртуальной машине. Делал через ноутбук, пробовал через проводную и беспроводную сеть. Бестолку.
У библиотек стоят самые последние версии как и у самого Python. В сертификатах windows я сам ничего не подписывал и не выдавал себе сертификат. Прошу помогите!

Я решил проблему. Оказывается можно через git bash ввести комманду:
openssl s_client -connect api.vk.com:443 -4 <<< "Q"
И скопировав значение begin sertificate в блокнот, сохранив в файле с расширением *.crt и добавив в доверенные корневые сертификаты системы можно решить данную проблему!

Единственное что, возможно сертификат придётся обновлять вручную каждый год.
